# I keep having this error, can someone try helping me on how to fix this issue

Tags: swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpjKm.png)

```
guard let urlString = urlString else {
            print("urlstring is nil")
            return
        }

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (URL(string: urlString))!)

        guard let player = player else {
            print("player is nil")
            return
        }
        player.volume = 0.5

        player.play()
    }
    catch {
        print("error occurred")
    }
```

ERROR CODE:Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `urlString` is not a valid URL or the API is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

Seems this statement `URL(string: urlString)` returns `nil`. Check what `urlString` variable looks like. I think it contains unallowable characters. In this case you need to change your `guard` statement to

```
guard let urlString = urlString?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
      let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
    print("urlstring is nil or invalid")
    return
}
do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `urlString` is not valid, Use this code:

```swift
guard let urlString = urlString, 
    let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("url is invalid")
            return
        }
do {
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    player.volume = 0.5
    player.play()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```